# Java: Test compiled program with input file inside program

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, compiled

I have a Java program that has a command line interface using [`Commons CLI`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) and processes an input file and writes an output file.

I use [`JUnit`](http://junit.org/junit4/faq.html) to test objects and their methods. However, I wonder if there is a possibility to test my whole compiled program with `JUnit` or any other way inside the tool rather than write an own test suite program as a seperate Java project.

What I would like to do:

1. Load an input file `test.txt` from a defined directory inside the Java project
2. Call the program: `java -jar -enableassertions MyTool.jar -i \Path\To\Test\test.txt`
3. See if any errors or assertions are thrown
4. Repeat this for multiple test input files

Comment: Yes - but you don't need to call `java -jar`. Store your test files on the classpath; then loop over them and create [parameterised tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests). In each test, write the file from the classpath to a temp location then invoke `main()` with a `String[]` containing `-i` and the full path to your temp location.

Comment: First of all, JUnit ist just a tool to drive testcases in an automated fashion; so of course: you can use for such things ... so, simply spoken, the answer is "yes", sure.

Comment: You can have a shell script / batch file that generates output, even capturing standard output and error with ` >out.txt 2>err.txt` and do a file compare with the expected output.